# Cannot access method in interface c#

Tags: c#

So I created an interface`ILogger.cs` that looks something like this:

```
public class ILogger {
   void Information(string message);
}
```

Then I created a class `Logger.cs` to implement the method:

```
public class Logger : ILogger
{
   public void Information(string message)
   {
      Trace.TraceInformation(message);
   }
}
```

I call `Information()` in another class like this:

```
public class Another() 
{
   private ILogger _logger = new Logger();

   _logger.Information("message");
}
```

I'm getting an error saying I cannot access `Information()` due to protection level. I understand why I have this message and if I just add `public` to the one in the interface. But what I don't understand is that, since I have already set `Information()` to be public in the `Logger.cs` class, I shouldn't have to do that kind of fix right?

Comment: I think you meant `public interface ILogger` instead of `public class ILogger`.

Comment: Putting `I` infront of an object doesn't make it an interface, it's just a naming convention.  You have to use the `interface` keyword.

Answer (score 4):

```
public interface ILogger {
   void Information(string message);
}
```

I guess you just need to change *class* to *interface* in implementation of your interface

Answer (score 4):

You declared ILogger as a class, not interface. That's why you can't use Information method. Default access modifier in c# is "private".

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Another() 
{
   private ILogger _logger = new Logger();

   _logger.Information("message");
}
```

The _logger is acts like the interface, which causes the Information() function get the visibility of the interface, which is internal by the way.

to solve this you should make the function a public function.

Comment: This won´t entirely solve the problem, as the `ILogger` is no interface and therefor the method `Information` from it cannot be abstract.